# Can I Linq query into multiple variables?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm a bit new to linq and I'm unsure if what I desire is possible. I basically have a class called User that contains a bunch of attributes. I want to only fill in the Name and ID fields that I'm getting from a query. My query gives me the appropriate results, but I am unsure of how to get it into user. This is the closest I get, but I realize it's incorrect.

```
 IEnumerable<User> UserList;
 UserList = (from o in dbContext.application_user
             join p in dbContext.project on application_user.user_id = project.project_manager
             select o);
```

This returns a list of User_ID, Firstname, and Lastname, but it doesn't fit into user. My user class has multiple variables, so I was thinking of approaching it by calling 3 IEnumerables, of types int, string, and string, if I could somehow fill all 3 from one query, and then set User = new User(name = x, id = x) etc. Such as

```
FNameList, LNameList, ID = *insert query here*
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct the `User` object inside the Linq query:

```
IEnumerable<User> UserList;
UserList = (from o in dbContext.application_user
            join p in dbContext.project on application_user.user_id = project.project_manager
            select new User(o.FName, o.LName, o.ID));
```

This assumes that `User` has a constructor taking three arguments like those, and that the properties on `o` are `FName`, `LName`, and `ID`, but you get the idea.  The `select` clause can be used to transform the results into whatever format you need.

Comment: You can `select new User() {FName=o.fName, LName=o.lName, ID=o.ID}` if there is a no-arg constructor and the properties are accessible, as well, in case you don't have the correct constructor.

Comment: @PeterLeppert: Indeed, any method of constructing the desired result inline will work.

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. It's pretty amazing that you can do that. Thanks.

Comment: @proseidon: As a learning experience, it's worth practicing to use the lambda syntax (the extension methods) as well as the Linq syntax.  It gives you a much more rounded understanding of how the whole thing works.  (In fact, the Linq syntax pre-compiles into the lambda syntax before being compiled into IL.)

Comment: @David This is the query syntax.  They are both LINQ syntaxes.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough, I always get the terminology skewed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just create your instances of `User` with an `Select` transformation.

```
var userQuery = from o in dbContext.application_user
                join p in dbContext.project on application_user.user_id = project.project_manager
                select o;

IEnumerable<User> UserList = from o in userQuery.ToList()
                             select new User() {Name = o.Lastname, ID = o.user_ID};
```

I don't know how your `User` class looks like, but you get the idea.